# how to deal with (ACTION_DAIL)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i made a project(credit recharge) out of two layouts..
in each layout i have a (number text field)
i want  to (ACTION_CALL) the two entering numbers in the text field together .

```
Button call = (Button)findViewByID(R.id.call);
call.setOncLICKListener(new OnClickListener() {  
public void(onClick view v) {
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.prase("tel: xxxx"));
}
```

i want to (ACTION_CALL) the users input in layout textField instated of "xxxx"
note: i tried a random number Instead of "xxxx" and the code work out .

Comment: Didn't got your question.Do you want to call the number after user inputs some number ?Please clarify more.

Comment: YES,, i want to call the two numbers that the user input ..in the first layout and the second one.. two numbers  one call.   thnks

Comment: why don't you use `setOnClicklistener` on `EditText`.